# How can I configure Google Remote Desktop so that it doesn't create a new session when I connect to it?

Tags: google-chrome, 20.04, remote-desktop, session

When I remote connect to Ubuntu using [TeamViewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer), I view the same session as the session in which TeamViewer is running.

However, when I connect using Google Remote Desktop it creates a new session by default:

[image]

How can I configure Google Remote Desktop so that it doesn't create a new session when I connect to it?

I tried with the following Google Remote Desktop hosts: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS x64 and 20.04.01 LTS x64.